# What does "Now listening on: http://[::]:80" mean?

Tags: docker, tcp, docker-compose

Have created an dotnet core application and when run the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

everything goes well but I don't understand what does the below line mean:

> Now listening on: http://[::]:80

Dockerfile content is:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source 
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 80 
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleCoreApp.dll"]
```

docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
 samplecoreapp:
   image: samplecoreapp
   build:
     context: ./SampleCoreApp
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Why is that I'm not seeing the IP address?

If i have a 3 VMs and if I want to run this application on VM2 then how can I deploy this docker container to VM2?

Comment: please share your docker-compose and related files. Otherwise, it's hard to understand issue.

Comment: It probably means your VM has multiple IP interafces and it listens to all of them on port 80

Answer (score 10):

> Now listening on: http://[::]:80

means: your application is telling you that it is listening on TCP port 80 on all IPv6 addresses it owns.

`[::]` is the short-hand notation for the [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` within an URL. Note that `::` is not a valid IPv6 address, but often is used as an alias for "all my IPv6 addresses".

Similarly, a web server that listens on TCP port 80 of all its IPv4 addresses usually reports that it is listening on `http://0.0.0.0:80`. In your case, it seems to be expecting IPv6 traffic instead. However, many applications are dual stack and listen to both, IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: "on all IPv6 addresses it owns" - what exactly does it mean to "own" addresses? The issue I am facing is my app1 is running on port 80 inside the container, I bind it to 33444 port on the host, and from app1 I am making a request to app2 running on the same host machine but a custom origin (say test.app2.com, thru hosts file loopback entries). Now app1 is getting the request it is making to app2, and app2 is not getting the request. app1 running inside the container also logs the line in the title of this question.